# Covariant derivatives of null tetrads

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

I am trying to understand the Newman Penrose null tetrads and facing some problems. Given $\ell_k$ is a null tetrad in [Newman-Penrose formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newman%E2%80%93Penrose_formalism), what is $\ell_{k;i}=?$

Answer (score 1):

The legs of the tetrads are just vector fields. Hence the covariant derivative of a tetrad leg is simply

$$\ell_{k;i} = \partial_i \ell_k - \Gamma^j_{ik}\ell_j$$

Comment: but in Newman Penrose christoffel symbol doesn't arises directly then how it will reates the Riccis rotation coefficient?

Comment: Sir in spin coefficients approach what will be the value

Answer (score 0):

In Newman-Penrose (NP) formalism, instead of using the standard four connections $∇_{u}$, we consider instead four locally-defined directional covariant derivatives on the flow of the tetrad, which are historically denoted by $(D,Δ,δ,\barδ)$.
Directional covariant derivatives of tetrad vector $l_{u}$ are:
$$Dl^{a}=(ε+\barε)l^{a}-\barκm^{a}-κ\bar m^{a}$$
$$Δl^{a}=(γ+\barγ)l^{a}-\barτm^{a}-τ\bar m^{a}$$
$$δl^{a}=(\barα+β)l^{a}-\barρm^{a}-σ\bar m^{a}$$
$$\barδl^{a}=(α+\barβ)l^{a}-\barσm^{a}-ρ\bar m^{a}$$